# installation problem while using USB disk and startup disk creator

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, usb

I'm trying to install Ubuntu in my hp elitebook 8460p laptop with 500 gb hard disk. I've created a USB boot device with Ubuntu 22.04, however after selecting language in the installation process it asks whether I need to erase the disk and install Ubuntu or to do something else. When I select the Something else option the only disk listed is sdb which is my USB, which is the USB stick I'm installing Ubuntu from. Running GParted my hard disk is detected, but only showing 465 GB instead of 500 GB, and 25 GB of 465 GB used and I had initially formatted it.

USB stick that I'm installing Ubuntu from:

[image: (which is the USB stick I'm installing Ubuntu from)]

GParted results:

[image: gparted results]

Comment: Welcome to AU. What's your end goal? Is there something on your HDD that you want to keep? Are you aiming for a dual boot system? If no to both, why not just erase and install (which is simpler)?

Comment: The two partitions in the internal drive are mounted as `/cdrom` and `/var/crash`. It seems to me that you have booted live from the internal drive (and not from the USB pendrive). Please check that the USB pendrive is really bootable with Ubuntu in another computer. If/when it is, use gparted to remove all partitions from the internal drive and then boot into the USB pendrive and try to install Ubuntu again.

Comment: final goal is to install only ubuntu

Comment: @RashidShisia, What you have now in the internal drive is not an installed system. It seems to be a live system, and it will interfere with the live system that you try to boot from the USB drive. -- If there  is no working operating system in your target computer's internal drive, can you use another computer to make a USB pendrive bootable with Ubuntu? In that case, you can use gparted to remove all partitions from the internal drive and then boot into the USB pendrive. When booted into the USB pendrive you can run the installer and create an installed system in your internal drive.